# python pandas dtypes detection from sql

Tags: python, sql, csv, pandas, dataframe

I am quite troubled by the behaviour of Pandas DataFrame about Dtype detection.

I use 'read_sql_query' to retrieve data from a database to build a DataFrame, and then dump it into a csv file.

I don't need any transformation. Just dump it into a csv file and change date fields in the form : **'%d/%m/%Y'**

However :

```
self.dataframe.to_csv(self.fic,
                   index=False,
                   header=False,
                   sep='|',
                   mode='a',
                   encoding='utf-8',
                   line_terminator='\n',
                   date_format='%d/%m/%Y
                   )
```

Would miss to transforme/format some date fields...

I tried to do it another way :

```
l = list(self.dataframe.select_dtypes(include=['datetime64']).columns)
for i in l:
    self.dataframe[i] = self.dataframe[i].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

I was about to be satisfied, but some more tests showed a weird behaviour :

**if my sql request only selects two nuplets :**

```
requete = 'select * from DOMMAGE_INTERET where doi_id in (176433, 181564)'
```

Everything works, whatever formating in the csv or in the DataFrame.

It detects date fields properly :

```
df.dtypes
doi_id                         int64
aff_id                         int64
pdo_id                         int64
doi_date_decision     datetime64[ns]
doi_date_mod          datetime64[ns]
doi_montant                  float64
doi_reste_a_payer             object
doi_appliquer_taux             int64
doi_date_update       datetime64[ns]
afg_id                         int64
dtype: object
```

**But when using a different selection :**

```
requete = 'select * from DOMMAGE_INTERET where rownum < 100'
```

It miss again. And actually, fields types are detected differently :

```
doi_id                         int64
aff_id                         int64
pdo_id                         int64
doi_date_decision             object
doi_date_mod          datetime64[ns]
doi_montant                  float64
doi_reste_a_payer             object
doi_appliquer_taux             int64
doi_date_update       datetime64[ns]
afg_id                         int64
dtype: object
```

As you can see : **'doi_date_decision' type does change depending of the request selection** but, of course, this is the same set of data !!!

Isn't it weird?

Do you have a explanation for this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `to-csv` operation does not convert all specified date fields because as you mention, not all datetime columns are read in as datetime format but show as string (*object* dtype) in current dataframe. This is the unfortunate side effect of reading from external sources as the imported system --this includes Python, SAS, Stata, R, Excel, etc.-- attempts to define columns usually by first few rows unless otherwise explicitly defined.

Fortunately, pandas's [`read_sql_query()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html#pandas.read_sql_query) maintains a parameter for `parse_dates`. So consider defining the dates during the read in operation as this argument takes a list or dictionary:

```
df = read_sql_query('select * from DOMMAGE_INTERET where rownum < 100', engine, 
                    parse_dates = ['doi_date_decision', 'doi_date_mod', 'doi_date_update'])
```

Alternatively, convert with [`pd.to_datetime()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) just after reading in and before `to_csv`:

```
df['doi_date_decision'] = pd.to_datetime(df['doi_date_decision'])
```

And most RDMS maintains datetime in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format, aligning to pandas format.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to dig into your issue without some data samples. However, you probably face either of the two cases:

- Some of the rows you select in your second case contain `NULL` values, which stops pandas interpret automatically your column as a datetime
- You have a different MDY convention in your database and some dates lower than 13rd of the month are parsed as dates while others aren't and are kept as strings until you convert manually in DMY

Comment: I know it's hard to figure out this issue without a dataset, especially when those datas are in a database.

Comment: The 2 rows collected with the query using a 'where in()' selection are included in the second query using 'where numrow < 100' selection. And yes, one has NULL value. Directly on the database, formating is exactly the same for every fields.

Comment: Could it be that, if a column start with a Null value, then Pandas cannot read this column dtype and mark it as 'object' ?

Comment: Test it with a where is not null against your sql query and see if it coerces again.

Comment: Unfortunately (or not :) !) i'm off for the weekend! So, i cannot run more tests. I just looked at this page : http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html. And it sounds like it should work. I'll run more tests on monday and read Pandas books this weekend. Thanks for your help. I'll give more info later. Cheers!

Comment: There is also some layer of libraries behind 'read_sql_query' : it uses sqlalchemy which use cx_oracle... got to test this too.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Boud and Parfait. Their answers are right :

All my tests shows that missing date fields can make Dtype detection to fail.

read_sql_query() has a parameter to define fields with date type. I guess to cure this problem.

Sadly, since now, I have been using a complete generic treatment to process a hundred of tables. 
To use 'read_sql_query' parameter 'parse_dates' would implies to do a prior work of metadata definition (like a json file describing each table).

Actually, I also found out that integers are changed to float when there is NaN field in the column...

If I would be reading csv flat files, I could understand that data type can be hard to detect... but from a database (read_sql_query)! Pandas has SqlAlchelmy as a dependence. And SqlAlchemy (and even any lower level Python database driver (cx_Oracle, DB API)) has reflection mechanism to detect data types. Pandas could have been using those metadatas to keep data types integrity.